# Hibernate one to one relation on same object

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have a transaction table which contains information about... transactions, some transactions are derived from a previous transaction, so that there can be a one to one relation between transactions.

I'm trying to set up annotation in hibernate to create this data structure, but I wasn't able to figure out or find how to do it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="transaction")
public class Transaction {
private String transactionid;
private Transaction derivedFrom;

   /**
     * @return the transactionid
     */
    @Id
    public String getTransactionid() {
        return transactionid;
    }
    /**
     * @param transactionid the transactionid to set
     */
    public void setTransactionid(String transactionid) {
        this.transactionid = transactionid;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "transaction", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Transaction getDerivedFrom() {
        return derivedFrom;
    }
    public void setDerivedFrom(Transaction derivedFrom) {
        this.derivedFrom = derivedFrom;
    }

}
```

Here is an example of code so you'll understand where I'm going with this... any idea on how to set up this relation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work, because of

```
mappedBy="transaction"
```

calls for bidirectional relationship and attribute name transaction on the other side of relationship. As you see from your code, you do not have such an attribute.

If you want **unidirectional one-to-one** from child to parent, following is way to go:

```
public class Transaction {
    private String transactionid;
    private Transaction parent;

    @Id
    public String getTransactionid() {
        return transactionid;
    }
    public void setTransactionid(String transactionid) {
        this.transactionid = transactionid;
    }
    @OneToOne
    public Transaction getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void setParent(Transaction parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Relationship is persisted by default to column name `parent_transactionid`, this can of course be changed by [@JoinColum](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html). Additionally you likely want to set unique contraint to column.

**To make relationship described above bidirectional one-to-one, just add following** (no other modifications needed):

```
private Transaction child;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent")
public Transaction getChild() {
    return parent;
}
public void setChild(Transaction child) {
    this.child = child;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a foreign key column "derived_id" in your transaction table, you can specify the join column

```
 @Entity
 public class Transaction 
 {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "derived_id", nullable = true)
    private Transaction derivedFrom;
 }
```